# Customize the uninstaller in IZPack

Tags: java, uninstallation, izpack, izpanel

Currently I have an installer and an uninstaller for my application and the problem is during uninstallation. i.e if I give a command like "java -jar uninstaller.jar" to uninstall my application I get one pop-up with one checkbox with the message "Force the deletion of /opt/app(this is installed path)" and two buttons: Uninstall and Quit.

The problem is if I don't check the checkbox and click on the Uninstall button, it says "Uninstall Successful", but the installed path is not deleted and only the Uninstall folder is deleted.

If I check the checkbox and click on "Uninstall" button, everything will go fine.

So, what I would prefer is if I check the checkbox then the Uninstall button should get enabled, in all other cases it should be disabled i.e when I run the uninstaller (java -jar uninstaller.jar) the Uninstall Button should come up disabled.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Comment: What version of izpack are you using?  The uninstaller will only uninstall the files it installed.  If the check is selected, it will delete everything under the install root directory.  Note, if under Windows, and process(es) have files open, the uninstaller will not be able to remove those files.  [https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/IZPACK-685](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/IZPACK-685) may interest you.

Comment: Hi, I just used "java -jar uninstaller.jar -f -x" to get rid of that check box.Now everything is fine.Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Could you add that as an answer and set it to solved then?